# Stripping URLs & Email from post submissions

Tags: filters, save-post, regex, post-content

I want to prevent users posting in this instance of WordPress from submitting URLs and Emails in posts.

I'm trying to do it via Regex but I'm not sure if I'm writing the Regex incorrectly because it doesn't seem to be stripping any URLs (haven't written the one for emails yet). Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong:

```
function censor_links( $content ) {
return preg_replace( '/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/', '[LINK NOT SHOWN]', $content );
    }
add_filter( 'the_content', 'censor_links' );
```

Should I be using a filter on [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `the_content` ([Click here for more info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)) hook to change the content while rendering the post/page.

This will be triggered when Post is being read from Database. So post content will not be changed in database but only filtered while rendering.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_email_and_url_from_post' );
function remove_email_and_url_from_post( $content ) {

    // Check if we're inside the main loop in a single post page.
    if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {

        // For emails
        $pattern = "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/";
        $replacement = "[removed]";
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

        // For urls
        $pattern = "/[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+/i";
        $replacement = "[removed]";
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

    }

    return $content;
}
```

Or same way you can use [`content_save_pre`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre) hook.

This will be triggered when post is being saved to database. So this will actually remove the filtered content from post and then save it to the database.

```
function remove_email_and_url_from_post( $content ) {
    return $content;
    $pattern = "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/";
    $replacement = "[removed]";
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

        // For urls
    $pattern = "/[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+/i";
    $replacement = "[removed]";
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'remove_email_and_url_from_post', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks Jitendra. I'll try this out and reply with the results.

Comment: This answer was perfect. One caveat is that the first suggestion may have conflict with contact form shortcodes that require email. What do you think? Is that a hard issue to deal with?

Comment: Nope actually I was wrong. The first one would work perfectly for embedded contact forms but I have not yet tested the second one but I would assume it wouldn't work if it was used since the shortcode with the email would be submitted and stripped out.